# System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'libuv'

Tags: asp.net-core, dnx, dnx50

For me it was never an issue before I installed Newtonsoft.Json package using dnu (`dnu install Newtonsoft.Json`), which added the package to the project and wrote an entry in `project.json` as `"Newtonsoft.Json": "8.0.1"` under dependencies node.

`dnu build` ran successfully after package got installed. Now when I ran the command `dnx web` the following error appeared suddenly!

Here is the full output:

```
{lamb} dnx web
System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'libuv': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.Networking.Libuv.NativeMethods.uv_loop_size()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.Networking.Libuv.loop_size()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.Networking.UvLoopHandle.Init(Libuv uv)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.KestrelThread.ThreadStart(Object parameter)
```

I have no idea how I can get rid of this!

Comment: I doubt there is a direct relationship. Which version of dnx and kestrel do you run?

Comment: Are you running on a non windows OS? Did you install libuv?

Answer (score 4):

IF you are using "Any CPU" Try to change your build platform of your project to x64 or x86. I have this problem when using "Any CPU" and changing it solve it to me. To do the following:

1. Right click at your project in VS
2. Click at properties
3. Go to "Build" tab.
4. Selec your value in "Plataform target"

Comment: This was my case.  x64/x86 works, but "Any CPU" does not.

Answer (score 2):

The Libuv dll is missing in one of the the package.

For OSX  you can solve   by copying the  missing file  by copy command.
use the following command

cp /Users//.dnx/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel/1.0.0-rc1-final/runtimes/osx/native/libuv.dylib   /Users//.dnx/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel/1.0.0-rc1-final/lib/dnxcore50/

Comment: I don't think libuv was missing int rc1-final Kestrel package. If this was the case in your case try cleaning package cache and restore again. The location you are copying the dylib to is incorrect. This path /Users//.dnx/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel/1.0.0-rc1-final/runtimes/osx/native/libuv.dylib is the correct location. You can read more on how native libs are handled in aspnet in my blog post on this very topic: http://blog.3d-logic.com/2015/11/10/using-native-libraries-in-asp-net-5/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have obsolete libuv library.
You can try to build and install it from sources. This is works for me on fedora-x64 linux:

```
# dnf install automake libtool wget
$ wget http://dist.libuv.org/dist/v1.8.0/libuv-v1.8.0.tar.gz
$ tar -zxf libuv-v1.8.0.tar.gz
$ cd libuv-v1.8.0
$ sh autogen.sh
$ ./configure
$ make
# make install
# cd /usr/local/lib
# cp libuv.* /usr/lib64/
# cp pkgconfig/libuv.pc /usr/lib64/pkgconfig/
```